# Increase max connection to node.js/socket.io

Tags: linux, node.js, centos, socket.io

I noticed that the maximum concurrent connections to `node.js` with `socket.io` is about 1000 connections.

Is it possible to increase that number with `ulimit` command on linux? setting the `ulimit` to 65536 can solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, it is likely. Default ulimit value is 1024

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `ulimit` for the user account node.js is running on to a higher number.